# Paypal no longer allows my customers to leave a note with their payment?

Tags: paypal

As far as I can tell this functionality disappeared from the standard paypal checkout flow around Sept/Oct 2016.

Does anyone know how to add the note functionality back?  I've searched through the paypal documentation and my selling preferences and come up with nothing.

I use a custom cart on my site that I built which then sends all of the user's products to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr via an encrypted button, if that makes any difference.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I regret to inform you the "Note to the seller" option is being deprecated with the move to new checkout experience(Hermes). You may use ON & OS fields to pass custom data.

Comment: Thank you.  What did you mean by "(Hermes)"?

Comment: The New checkout flow is called as Hermes and the old checkout flow is called as classic.
Note to seller option is available in classic, but not available at Hermes.